# JS object literal, this context changing

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling

I'm in the process of improving my Javascript structure and trying to work out which patterns I like, I have the following:

```
var aThing = (function() {

  var module;

  return {

    init: function() {
      module = this;
      console.log(module);
    },

  };

})();
```

When I run `aThing.init();` it logs `Object {init: function}`, this is what I want, the problem occurs when I do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', aThing.init, false);
```

This logs `#document`. It seems that `this` is changing when I run the function without the parenthesis and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about execution context. Although your init method lives inside your aThing module, you're executing it elsewhere so your use of the "this" keyword will refer to the execution context.

Rather than writing the event handler outside your module, you should consider leveraging your very module to handle that. It can be done from inside your module's init method and this will give you a cleaner structure as your bucketing everything regarding your module inside the module itself rather than doing somethings outside of it and others inside.

See below:

```js
var aThing = (function() {

  var module;

  return {
    
    init: function() {
      module = this;

      // Handle event binding from somewhere within your module
      document.addEventListener('click', module.doSomething, false);
    },
    
    doSomething: function () {
      console.log('Doing something.');
    }
  };

})();

// Initialize your module
aThing.init();
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this really helped wrapping my head around a few concepts, cheers!

Comment: No prob, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `'document'` reference because the `init()` function s called in document context. Either you can bind the function to what ever object you want.

```
aThing.init.bind(aThing)
```

Or you can refer with module if its like,

```
var aThing = (function() {
    var module = {
        name  : 'My module',
        init : function() {
          alert(module.name);
        }

   };
  return module;

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, because the context in the event handler is going to be `document`. Either use:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    aThing.init();
}, false);
```

or

```
document.addEventListener('click', aThing.init.bind(aThing), false);
```